# How to get the category page view mode in final_price.php file in Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, catalog

I am displayed the tier price like **table structure** in `Category List/Grid Mode` successfully. Now I am trying to disable the table structure in `Category Grid Mode`. But I can't get the category view mode `$block->getMode()` in `root/module-catalog/view/base/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml` file.

**Category List Mode**

[image]

**Category Grid Mode**

[image]

In Grid Mode UI not well so I need to disable or need to show normal price. So how to get the Category page view mode in this file. So that I can write logic on this page.

Any help on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get direct mode in `final_price.phtml` because in `\Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\RendererPool` Magento doesn't set any child `toolbar` block.

In list page you are getting because when you look at `\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct` there is one method available for that

```
public function getMode()
    {
        return $this->getChildBlock('toolbar')->getCurrentMode();
    }
```

It means Magento using toolbar block for that.

---

I am not sure how you are changing `final_price.phtml` and which block you are using, But if you are using custom block then you can simple achieve by injecting `toolbar` block in `constructor`.

```
<?php
namespace Test\Module\Block;

class Product extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{

  protected $_toolbar;  


  public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar $_toolbar
    ) {
        $this->_toolbar = $_toolbar;
    }
    public function getMode()
    {
        return $this->_toolbar->getCurrentMode();
    }

}
```

Now you can access `$block->getMode()` in phtml files.

---

### Dirty way

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$modecheck = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar')->getCurrentMode();
```

In `$modecheck` variable you can get current mode.

***Note: I am against of direct loading object with objectManager, for better impact you can inject it in your constructor***

Comment: I am using registry to get the view mode from `list.phtml` first time working next time I mean when I changing Grid Mode not updating the log. I figured that next time on wards it's rendering from cache. `$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $registry = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry');
    $registry->register('Category_Page_View_Mode', $block->getMode());$view_Mode = $registry->registry('Category_Page_View_Mode')` So how to do this?

Comment: Instead of $registry = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry'); try with the $registry = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\Registry');

Comment: let me check and get back to you

Comment: it's working only first time. even though not updating log `\file_put_contents('ViewMode.txt', print_r("\n" . $mode_check,true), FILE_APPEND);` when I changed the view Modes. But when I Refresh the cache it's working @ first time.

Comment: What is the $mode_check ? And If you are using mine code then you can slice change my code $modecheck = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar')->getCurrentMode();

Comment: see my edit......

Comment: I am getting the correct value in my setup even If cache is enable

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48586/discussion-between-magento-two-and-keyur-shah).